# @HostListener on mouse down not adding style to element

Tags: angular, angular-directive, mousedown

I'd like to add some style to element while mouse down on some element (before element will be dragged by ng-dragula), but somehow, this style property applied to element only when mouse button released.
This is how it look like:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appDragging]'
})
export class DraggingDirective {

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private el: ElementRef) { }

  @HostListener('mousedown') onMouseDown() {
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'cursor', 'move');
  }
```

Comment: It works: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qeatzl?file=src/app/app.component.ts make sure you added your directive to the declarations arrays of your app.module

Comment: @Ploppy, I did, it was created with ng cli and otherwise I'll get compilation error.

Comment: Are you using ng-dragula or ng2-dragula?

Comment: @night_owl, "ng2-dragula": "^2.1.1",

Comment: @Ploppy, yes, it's working when mouse button released, but I need it work when mouse button down and hold.

Comment: @andrey.shedko then you should not style the div but the body